# Text Field - Action and outlet

Tags: ios5.1

Can the same Text Field be set up as an "Action" and "Outlet"?

I am trying to use the touch Action to Segue to DatePicker and the outlet to capture the results in the same text field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But be careful of infinite loops. If the action method for textFieldA is actionA, and actionA sets the value of textFieldA, you could lock up the process.